# PHP Array sorting using child nodes?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Ok I have the following array:

```
Array
(
   [0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 6
        [name] => This Course
        [time] => 1288082700
        [description] => blah blah . 
        [link] => http://this.com/?g=5
        [course] => 22
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [name] => Workshop
        [time] => 1287561600
        [description] => This description
        [link] => http://this.com/?g=5
        [session] => 8
        [course] => 23
        [type] => standard
        [adobelink] => 
    )
```

)

How can I sort this entire array by using the inner 'time' key ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `usort` function as:

```
function cmp($a,$b) {
        return $a['time'] - $b['time'];
}

usort($arr,'cmp');
```

[**Working link**](http://www.ideone.com/4PWxI)

Comment: +1 for shortness (how embarrassing that I not thought about that) and link

Answer (score 4):

Use [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php):

> This function will sort an array by its values using a user-supplied comparison function. If the array you wish to sort needs to be sorted by some non-trivial criteria, you should use this function.

Example:

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a['time'] == $b['time']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['time'] < $b['time']) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($array, 'cmp');
```

Of course this will fail if an array has no `time` element. What should happen then depends on your requirements so I will leave the error handling to you ;)

Answer (score 3):

Use PHP usort() function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

First, define a function that will decide on compare result for your data structure:

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a['time'] == $b['time']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['time'] < $b['time']) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Then call usort() and give the nmae of your function to it:

```
usort($array, "cmp");
```

You're done!

Answer (score 2):

[`uasort()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) will [maintain your keys](http://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php)<sup>1</sup>.

```
uasort($a, function($a, $b) {
    $a = $a['time']; // Assuming keys exist
    $b = $b['time'];
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return $a < $b ? -1 : 1; // Reverse < if sort order is wrong
    }
});
```

*Anonymous function syntax requires PHP 5.3+*! Pass the name of the comparison function if <5.3 (see other answers).

<sup>1)</sup> In case you care about the keys, too. If not, just use the `usort()` approach found in abundance above :) The comparison function are basically identical (except for @codaddict's [elegant approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966859/php-array-sorting-using-child-nodes/3966933#3966933)).

Comment: Adding to Felix's comment, specifically it's the anonymous function that requires PHP 5.3, and not `uasort()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
http://dk.php.net/usort

function sortByTime($a, $b)
{
 if ($a['time'] > $b['time'])
 {
  return 1;
 }
 else if ($a['time'] < $b['time'])
 {
  return -1;
 }
 return 0;
}

usort($yourArray, 'sortByTime');
```

Comment: would these functions work if there was more than 2 entries though?

Comment: Yes! as virtually all answers here are similar and it worked! Thanks guys!!

Comment: This functionn will work with large numbers of entries. PHP's usort calls the named function for every pair of values in the array.